# Android - where to add onClickListener on custom notification?

Tags: android, onclick, notifications

I have my custom notification:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

// build notification
// the addAction re-use the same myIntent to keep the example short
Notification myNotification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("My App")
    .setContentText("Service is not running")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(myPendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_mic, "Start Service", myPendingIntent).build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);
```

I'm simply asking where should I put onClickListener to my button generated by `.addAction()`?

Answer (score 1):

While clicking on the notification, your MainActivity will get opened.

So in onCreate of your activity, you can put your onClick Code.

To be specific, add a line above your pending intent creation:

```
myIntent.putExtra("FromNotification", true);
```

Then in the onCreate of your MainActivity check like :

```
if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FromNotification", false)) {
    // Do your onclick code.
}
```

Comment: I assume when the button is clicked, it will first navigate to the main activity, then executes the onCreate and detects if it does came from the notification? Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter to `addAction` is a `PendingIntent` that should correspond to what action you want to take when that action is clicked. This can either call a `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service` that then handles the action and does whatever is required.